# Do I need a moisture barrier between sub floor wolmanit and engineered floating bamboo clip together flooring?

Tags: flooring

I'm using walmanite 3' by 5' by 1/4" over an original Pine slate floor my grandfather put in. do i NEED to put some type of barrier like tar paper between them? there has never been a barrier and no insulation. my mother added padding and carpet but now she  wants engineered bamboo clip together floating floor that will  have a moister barrier padding between it  and the wolmanit.

Answer (score 1):

The floating floor needs the thin foam pad for it to function properly and most of the floating floor pads already have a vapor barrier as part of it.  But adding an additional barrier is not needed (unless you have moisture issues).

If you where doing a nail down install (instead of float) I would recommend rosin or tar paper between the the floors.  But it would not be for vapor barrier but to reduce noise between the two floors rubbing.